# Unreachable code Detected in C# while returning 2 values

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```cs
public int Number;
public int NumberTwo;
int GiveDouble() {
    return Number * 3;
    return NumberTwo * 5; // compiler says this is unreachable
}
void Start() {
    int returnedNumber = GiveDouble();
    // ...
    int returnedNumber2 = GiveDouble();
    // ...
}
```

Or [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDi3f.jpg)

I am trying to return 2 values from one function to 2 distinct variables in an another function.

In this case... I am sending 2 values from `GiveDouble()` function to the variables `ReturnedNumber` and `ReturnedNumber2` in the `Start()` function. The inputs are given in `UNIY engine`.

Please check the picture I added..where the popup says unreachable code detected at the second return function.

My question may be not so reasonable. I am still learning now. I wanna know why is that coming?

Comment: look into [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples).

Comment: The compiler is right; the second `return` is unreachable. If you want multiple returns, then you either need to return a composite value (such as a tuple/value-tuple/custom type), or use `yield return` in an iterator block

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is right; one call can only return one value. You're calling the method *twice*, but that doesn't *resume* a method - it calls it again from the start, so the first result will be returned each time.

One option here could be "value tuples":

```
    (int, int) GiveDouble()
    {
        return (Number * 3, NumberTwo * 5);
    }
    void Start()
    {
        (int returnedNumber, int returnedNumber2) = GiveDouble();
    }
```

or with better naming on the tuple:

```
    (int Foo, int Bar) GiveDouble()
    {
        return (Number * 3, NumberTwo * 5);
    }
```

Comment: You can also just use a regular tuple, it depends on if your context suits `Item1` and `Item2` or literally anything else. `return new Tuple<int, int>(number * 3, numerTwo * 5);`

Comment: Note that this depends on the Unity version since tuples were not supported in the past and even now require a lot configuration.

Answer (score 1):

just to be clear, when you say `return Number * 3;` you end that method there, and return `Number * 3`. return makes the compiler drop out of the method and move on, so basically its like saying your done with that method, thats why the code is unreachable.

```
int GiveDouble() {
    return Number * 3;
    return NumberTwo * 5; // compiler says this is unreachable
}
```

erase this and try

```
int TimesThree(int one){
return one*3;
}
int TimesFive(int two){
return two*5;
}
```

then change:

```
   int returnedNumber = GiveDouble();
    // ...
    int returnedNumber2 = GiveDouble();
```

to

```
    int returnedNumber = TimesThree(Number);
    // ...
    int returnedNumber2 = TimesFive(NumberTwo);
```